# Speech to text/ speech recognition

Tags: java, speech-recognition

Does anyone know of a way that I can either code a program (preferably in java), or use an existing program or API that will listen to the microphone and convert what you are saying into text and save to a file? I do not want it to have any fancy features, I just want to have a lightweight speech to text program that will use very little resources so that is will be fast and simple.

Thanks in advance for any help! ☻

Comment: you can do it using Android API. see this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/

Comment: Look at [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/). Java library is [here](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nilpmet,

I must have done this at least a dozen times using CMU's [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/), their continuous-speech, speaker-independent recognition system. Sphinx has a Java [API](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) which is pretty great.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's speech API, [demonstrate here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html).

[Here](https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2) is a reverse engineering of this API, you can get your speech API key [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).